# Sharing drive contents using Samba - What harddrive format?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, samba, hard-drive

What format should my harddrives be if I am putting them in a ubuntu server with the intention of sharing the drives contents using samba to other PC's, Macs and linux PC's?

I don't know if I should be formatting the drive for windows, mac or linux? Any input would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but [SF] is for Professional System Administrators (et al) only. Your question appears to be for non-professional use and might be on-topic on [SU] or [unix.SE], but I am not migrated it there as you have the answer already. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should be formatted as Linux drives, e.g. with ext4 or XFS file systems, as they have to be read by Ubuntu and Samba.  Also, you **urgently** need to read up on what you are planning to do, as you obviously don't understand the most fundamental aspects of it.